# how do I use values from an array inside a function in another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, binary

I created a function in Javascript that convert decimal numbers to binary, and I used an array to store the binary numbers, and made the function returns the array, what I want is, how do I get the values of that array and use it outside the function or in another function?

thats the function I was talking about, and that array I want is called numArray.

```js
        function decimalToBinary(Num) {
     let bits = ''; 
     let rem = Num; 
     for(let i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
      let divisor = Math.pow(2, i); 
      let bitValue = Math.floor(rem / divisor);
      bits = bits + bitValue; 
      rem = rem % divisor; 
     }
     
     let numArray = []; 
     
     for(let i = 0; i < bits.length; i++){
      let bit = bits.charAt(i);
      let binaryNums = parseInt(bit);
      numArray.push(binaryNums); 
     }
     
     return numArray; 

     }

    /*
    what I want to do is to use a specific value from inside that array 
    and use inside a second function, and then use if-statement to get the 
    result I want
    */

    function second() {
        //if-statement 
        if(numArray[2] === 1){
        //do something
        }else{
        //do something else
        }

      }
```

Comment: You can define the array in a scope which is accessible to both of the functions.

Comment: how do I do that? you mean defining the function outside the function, so it could be accessible in both of the two functions?

Comment: You can define the variable outside.

Comment: I would advice against that approach - you will end up modifying the array contents in multiple places which will lead to difficult-to-manage bugs. Your function seems somewhat sensible and it *returns* the array that you want. So instead, please show us a little context. How are you using the function?

Comment: I edited the code above so you can see an example for how I want to use the values of the array inside a second function

Comment: @Obada in what context you're calling the second funnction is it called immediately or on some other events ?

Comment: immediately, I guess. Sorry, I am new to javascript, so what do you mean exactly? What I had in mind is that I wanted to make the first function (deciamlToBinary) return the array and then I can take the values from the array and use them inside another function that I make. the second function will take one value from inside the array and put it in an if-statement and get a specific result based on what number it was (weather is was, 0 or 1) in the array. does that make any sence? Again, sorry for being like this, I am new to javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
var binary = [] ;
function decimalToBinary(Num) {
    // do some logic push the output in binary
return binary; 
}

function second(argument){
 //Here you can access the binary
}
```

**P.S:- This is anti pattern if you update your question i can tell some more way to do it.**

Comment: While technically correct, I think this approach will be harmful in most circumstances I can come up with. It is not generally a good idea to 1) manipulate outer scope in a function, 2) return a value from an outer scope.

Comment: @SamiHult i know this is anti-pattern. but this only i can answer when the op is not specific about he's gonna use it second function or how he's calling the second function

Comment: I agree, so let's wait for an update and then get back to the matter.